# Video Buffering Customization for background video in a page

Tags: html, html5-video

I am creating a page having a video in background with HTML5.

I want to play the video after it buffered 70%. So that once the user play the video the video should not buffered.

Any one have a solution for this ?

Here is my code for video:

```
    <div class="container">
<video id="video" poster="data:image/gif,AAAA" width="64" height="64" autoplay loop muted="muted" volume="0">
  <source src="video/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/video1.ogv" type="video/ogv">
  <source src="video/video1.webm" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
```

I have tried some java script also

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myButtonId" type="button">Get first buffered range</button><br> 

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function myFunction() { 
  alert("Start: " + vid.buffered.start(0) + " End: "  + vid.buffered.end(0));
  document.getElementById("myButtonId").click();

if(vid.buffered.end(0)>40){

 vid.autoplay = true;
    vid.load();

}


} 
</script>
```

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: Some browsers doesn't allow the video to buffer 70%. Depends from browser to browser. Have you tried "canplaythrough" event?

Comment: that is not working for me @Govinda